# Attaching plastic to glass

Tags: adhesive, glass

The people who repaired my wife’s car’s windshield didn’t do a good job, and the little plastic enclosure surrounding the mirror (containing a light and a sunglasses holder) has fallen off. I tried some superglue and it fell off again within a week, presumably because it gets so hot and humid in the car (Georgia summer, parked outside). What’s a simple and reliable glue to attach plastic to glass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Glue E6000 is quite strong also but requires a full 24hours to cure and must be untouched in the mean time. It should harden after about 30 mins but it's really best to give it 24hours.  Also its a flexible glue so its less likely to give out from vibration. They also have a "industrial" variant called e6800. I have used it for a few years now and its great. glass is listed but i have no personal experience with that.

Brands like loctite make glue for holding Rear view mirrors to glass so that may be a option.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You really need a glue that's recommended for rear view mirrors due to the extreme heat.+1

Comment: Yup, everything with automotive is harder.

Comment: And any product designed for glueing mirror supports on cars needs *both** surfaces to be super clean and there are products for that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Frameless fishtanks are held together with 100% silicone. In many cases that's also what's holding the windshield in place on the car, to the best of my recollection. Cure time is moderately long, so the prior suggestion to look at rearview mirror glue is probably going to be easier.

Things need to be very clean (regardless of what type of glue you are using.)

Comment: The product used for car screens never sets solid so the body flexing does not break the glass.